# Applying a new colour scheme on GdalRasterLayer using SharpMap

Tags: raster, gdal, c#, .net, sharpmap

I'm currently developing a surface water modelling system in C# (.NET) and am using the SharpMap control as my mapping component. It's all going well, but there's one thing I'm struggling with. I cannot seem to be able to change the colour scheme on some `GdalRasterLayer` layers. The data comes in the form of ESRI Ascii Grid files (.ASC) and loads fine if I don't change anything from default. I've tried changing the `ColorBlend` without any success; in fact applying a `ColorBlend` causes the layers to not be displayed.

The code I've tried:

```
string layerName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);
GdalRasterLayer rasterLayer = new GdalRasterLayer(layerName, filename);
rasterLayer.ColorBlend = SharpMap.Rendering.Thematics.ColorBlend.DigitalTerrainModelMOHID;
Mapper.mymap.Layers.Insert(0, rasterLayer);
Mapper.mymap.ZoomToExtents();
RefreshMap(); // my own refresh method which calls the SharpMap control's refresh
```

I've also tried creating my own `ColorBlend` object and using that; no difference. Am I barking up the wrong tree? Is `ColorBlend` the right thing to be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to wrap the ascii files in a [GDAL Virtual Raster](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_vrttut.html) (*.vrt) file and apply a color table to the file. This had the added benefit of easily being able to colour all the files using the same colour range and including them all as one layer in my map.